# How to set JavaFX Circle Radius using CSS?

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml, radius

is there any CSS property that would set the Circle's radius? Intuitively I've tried "fx-radius" or "fx-size" but that's not it. I don't want to set each circle radius separately in fxml file;

```
<Circle fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="400.0" layoutY="300.0" radius="20.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" styleClass="Circle" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no size/radius CSS property, but there are properties for scaling a circle: -fx-scale-x/y/z.

> The Circle node has all the properties of Shape and Node.

You can see all properties in the docs:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#circle